# Multiple select using JPA

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I use JPA on my JEE6 application running on Glassfish.

I want to select multiple records from a table. Let's say each record has a column named "serialnumber" And I have a dynamic list of serial numbers and from table I want to select the records with those serial numbers.

Is there a way to this without using a for loop?

Comment: now you sure get that you should use IN clause ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write NamedQuery in JPQL which selects all entities with given serial numbers using IN statement (just like in plain SQL)

Something like:

```
SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.serialNumber IN :serialNumbers
```

And then in DAO layer method you pass array of serial numbers to the query:

```
query.setParameter('serialNumbers', serials);
```

Comment: thank you, and what if I need something multiple; like a list of records where serialnumber is blah and status is blah

Comment: then you extend WHERE statement with: WHERE i.serialNumber IN :serialNumbers AND i.status = :status

Answer (score 3):

You can use `IN` clause which takes list as a `parameter`

Ex

```
select DISTINCT obj from Obj  where obj.number IN :numbersList
```

See [**Here**](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html) for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with JPQL and `IN` clause:

`select item from Item item where item.serial IN :serials`